# Export analytics from MarketingCloud to Google Analytics

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics, google-analytics, email-tracking

I have a big bunch of data from the past 3 years about more than 20 Triggered Sends  delivery process. This data exists in MarketingCloud and is what system provides on the Tracking Send feature.

is there a way to export all this information to Google Analytics?

I have some coverage done in GA, for example the links opened.

I saw there's a feature in SFMC on the Tracking's tab called *Data* so I have tried to export but there's an error "Template not found: PagerInfo"